# vuelidate ValidateEach component in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuelidate

did someone know how in vuelidate how to  use the ValidateEach component  for  collection validation  without using the v-model  on the component

Comment: The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and clear problem statement. What did you try and what didn't work? Why is v-model a problem?